# Reading excel file to dict, but only one row is shown

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading an XLS file with xlrd

```
    import xlrd
    iedb = {} #Empty dictionary 
    book = xlrd.open_workbook('sampledata.xlsx')
    sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    for i in range(1,sh.nrows): #skips first line.
         iedb[sh.cell_value(rowx=i,colx=1)] = \
              sh.cell_value(rowx=i,colx=2)
```

My file of excel is 'sampledata.xlsx'

```
Reference   IEB ID  Epitope Name
I_N_Glaspole_Allergy_2005   221 Ara_h_2_(1-20)
I_N_Glaspole_Allergy_2005   920 Ara_h_2_(10-29)
I_N_Glaspole_Allergy_2005   921 Ara_h_2_(19-38)
I_N_Glaspole_Allergy_2005   922 Ara_h_2_(28-47)
```

So, I get the desired output as follows:

```
{221.0: 'Ara h 2 (1-20)', 920.0: 'Ara h 2 (10-29)', 921.0: 'Ara h 2 (19-38)', 922.0: 'Ara h 2 (28-47)'}
```

But in the program if i change the column numbers to 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2 i.e.:

```
    iedb[sh.cell_value(rowx=i,colx=0)] = \
         sh.cell_value(rowx=i,colx=1)
```

I expect the output with 4 entries but it gives only one entry as follows:

```
{'I N Glaspole Allergy 2005': 922.0}
```

Please explain..My version is 3.6.4

Comment: `dict` keys have to be unique but `Reference` is all the same value, so only one entry in the `dict`. You may want to consider a `list` and append a `tuple` for each row, e.g. `iedb = []` ... `iedb.append((sh.cell_value(rowx=i,colx=0), sh.cell_value(rowx=i,colx=1)))`

Comment: Thanks mate! My bad! @AChampion

Answer (score 0):

`Reference` column has all the same value and `dict` keys have to be unique, so each entry is just overwriting the previous entry.

You have a couple of options, use a `list`, e.g.:

```
iedb = []
...
for i in range(1,sh.nrows):
    iedb.append((sh.cell_value(rowx=i,colx=0), sh.cell_value(rowx=i,colx=1)))
```

Or make the `value` in the `dict` a list of results:

```
iedb = {}
...
for i in range(1,sh.nrows):
    iedb.setdefault(sh.cell_value(rowx=i,colx=0), []).append( sh.cell_value(rowx=i,colx=1))
```